# In Ruby On Rails CLI, how can I list Helper Paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, path

If I enter `bin/rails routes` into terminal, I see a list of routes for my Ruby application.

[image: CLI Routes Columns]

If I visit the address `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` I see the same routes, but with the additional column of `Helper`. These helper paths are useful to have a list of to hand, but I don't want to open up the webpage each time.

[image: Routes Web Screenshot with Helper Paths]

Is there a way I can run `bin/rails routes` in terminal, with the extra column to show helper paths? (`articles_path`, `new_articles_path` etc)

I'm on Rails 5.1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter `bin/rails routes` into terminal, you see the `prefix` column.
That's what you are looking for.

So if there is a prefix: `welcome_index`, there exists `welcome_index_path, welcome_index_url` helpers.

You can append _path or _url to prefix to get the name of a route helper.

Comment: A-ha! Can't believe I didn't spot the correlation. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: more info:  `_path` is the helper method that gives relative routes to access your app and `_url` gives the absolute routes to access your app

Answer (score 1):

The helpers are listed in the leftmost column of the output of `bin/rails routes`. Just append `_path` or `_url`.